# AWS S3 API lite alternative for PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I want to use an S3 compatible service to store some backups. The only things I need is uploading/deleting backups and getting download links. That's it.

For PHP AWS has a nice SDK but it is overkill for my simple project. I want to keep it lite. AWS SDK is ~40MB.

Is there any alternative libraries or native PHP methods instead of using huge AWS PHP SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You could also easily use CURL to download/fetch items from S3

To upload a file to Amazon S3 via curl, you need to perform the following steps:

1. Obtain your AWS access key ID and secret access key.
2. Set the correct region for your S3 bucket.
3. Set the correct ACL (Access Control List)
   for the uploaded file.
4. Use curl to upload the file to S3.

As example, the PUT code would look like below

```
curl -X PUT -T /path/to/local/file.jpg \
-H "x-amz-acl: public-read" \
-H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" \
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/your-bucket-name/file.jpg" \
-H "Authorization: AWS ACCESS_KEY_ID:SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
```